# How to send and receive multiple integer values through serial comm for Arduino Micro and HC05 bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, softwareserial, arduino-micro, hc-05

I need to send gyroscope values and a voice command flag and counter with a start and end marker through serial in the format <2,4,5,6> through Arduino Software serial using the HC05 Bluetooth module between Arduino Micro boards. I can send values in the struct format. But it seems that the order of the struct gets changed after a few seconds of receiving on the other side. How can I send these values in the mentioned format? I am new to this. Please help me out. It would also help if I could get suggestions on how to receive and parse this data of this format in the correct order/way.

Comment: why do you use SoftwareSerial? Micro has Serial1 for RX/TX pin

Comment: @Juraj , I need to monitor the values since the transmission is so fast and needs the least latency possible. Besides, I could never get my bluetooth modules to work on hardware serial. Please provide me with a demo code or some link. Are there two hardware serial on Arduino Micro? I'm not sure. Please enlighten me.

Comment: there is USB named Serial and UART named Serial1. pins RX/TX are Serial1

Comment: @Juraj , I have been trying wireless communication using Serial but not Serial1. Is that the reason I am unable to send? Also, the question still remains how I can send, receive and parse the data to be sent in the format <2,3,4,5>

Comment: where are you sending the serial data?

Comment: @jsotola , arduino micro to arduino micro. Sending the values of gyroscope sensor and voice command flag. I wanna move the mouse cursor using that data.

Answer (score 1):

Try Google Protobuf it's really awsome. I use it every time when I connect C# app to STM but it can be used in this case as well. U use Protobuf to encode your message and COBS do remove zeros from message so you can slap it on the end to know when the packet ends

Comment: Google Protobuf does work on AVR Arduino?